# Groovy Calling/Looping through JSON Objects

Tags: json, groovy, treemap

I am using groovy's `RESTClient` to make an `HTTP GET` Request and have a `JSON` response object that looks like this

```
{   
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 1,
    "count": 4,
    "items": [{
        "id": 291938,
        "type": email,
        "folder": "1234",
        "isDraft": "false",
        "number": 349,
        "owner": {
            "id": 1234,
            "firstName": "Jack",
            "lastName": "Sprout",
            "email": "jack.sprout@gmail.com",
            "phone": null,
            "type": "user"
        },
        "mailbox": {
            "id": 1234,
            "name": "My Mailbox"
      }
    }]
}
```

I set my code like so

```
def Client = new RESTClient('https://api.myapi.net/v1/conversations/' )
helpscout.setHeaders([Authorization: "Basic 1234", Accept: 'application/json'])
def resp = Client.get(contentType: JSON)
def myResponseObject = resp.getData()
```

I need to be able to loop through multiple API calls/JSON objects, and store all of the response items into their own variables/classes, and output them as necessary.

I'm coming from a python background, and am used to being able to call a specific item by saying `responseObject['items']['id']`, but in this case I can't do that.

My question to you is, how am I able to access one of these items, and do whatever I need to do with it/store it into a variable

This is my debugger output below
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the sample json you provided is the same as what the endpoint is returning?

Comment: Bah! updated the actual JSON Output in the debugger It now prints out integers

Comment: It would be much easier to give some help if you would provide the actual JSON you get from the endpoint as text rather that providing a screenshot of debugger. According to the screenshot the JSON is totally different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `getData()` returns a `Map` you can just reference the fields in the JSON like so:

```
...
def myResponseObject = resp.getData()
def page = myResponseObject.page
def count = myResponseObject.count
println page // prints 1
println count //prints 4

// Print all items
myResponseObject.items.each {
    println "item: $it"
}

// The python example responseObject['items']['id'] in groovy is
responseObject.items[0].id

// To get the first items createdAt field (according to the image)
println responseObject.items[0].createdAt
```

Comment: I tried it and page returns null, see the screenshot that I added to the question

Comment: According to the image the `myResponseObject` has one entry called `item`, try it like this: `myResponseObject.item.page`

Comment: that gets items stores into a variable, then what do you do to call a specific item or field?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean calling a specific item, could you give an example what you want to do with the fields?

Comment: Like how would I reference myResponseObject.items[1][4] ? It should give an output of 2016-08-10T19:17:30Z

Comment: What would you expect as a result according to the screenshot you provided for `myResponseObject.items[1][4]`?

Comment: 2016-08-10T19:17:30Z